# Find all possible combinations of numbers

Tags: c, combinations, permutation

**Background (TL;DR – the original post)**

I am currently really struggling with this problem in C and I am wondering if anyone knows what do do. I need to print all possible solutions to a cryptarithmetic problem like BASE + BALL = GAMES.  For example one solution here is: A=4 B=7 E=3 G=1 L=5 S=8 M=9 which corresponds to 7483 +7455= 14938. So my task is to find the correct digit to character mapping for this to be true. I can use digits from 0-9 and each digit can only be assigned to one letter. The solution needs to be recursive btw. My thinking process was to find all the unique characters from the 3 strings and assign them a digit and then check if the solution to the above relationship is true. In case it's not true I need to try a different combination of digits to characters. I just don't know what method I need to use to cover all possible combinations. I don't necessarily want the code, I am just looking for someone to explain to me the algorithmic logic begind it or provide any possible resources.

Edit: What I mean by cryptarithmetic problem is a problem where the user gives as input 3 strings that create an equation like SEND + MORE = MONEY. This equation is solved by assigning a unique digit from 0-9 to each letter like I showed in the example above.

So we want a program to do something like this:

Input : s1 = SEND, s2 = "MORE", s3 = "MONEY"
Output : One of the possible solution is:
D=1 E=5 M=0 N=3 O=8 R=2 S=7 Y=6

If you try to replace each character with it's assigned digit you will see that the equation created holds true. I need a program to do exactly that, meaning to find the correct mapping of digits to character so that the equation produced will be true.

**Actual question**

The actual question is just about seeking possible assignments of numbers to letters, not about solving the cryptarithmic puzzle in general. It is:

> How to generate all variations of length `k` from the set of ten single-digit non-negative numbers?

In other words, find all sequences of length `k` (for some 0 < k ≤ 10) of integer numbers 0 through 9, with no repeating numbers within a sequence.

Comment: You need us to tell way more details about your "cryptarithmetic problem".

Comment: @paladin Okay sorry, can you please tell me what more I need to add?

Comment: For example a clear definition of your "cryptarithmetic problem".

Comment: @paladin I tried to provide some more context. Hope it's more clear now, else give me some more feedback.

Comment: What have you done? Can you share some thoughts about the algorithm, the phases of solution, data structure? Some code you already have?

Comment: @CiaPan I haven't really started. I provided the problem just for a bit of extra context. My main question was in general how to find all possible combinations of numbers from 0-9 that could be uniquely mapped in with 6 characters. For example string = ABCDEF. One combination could be 123456, another 234678. How can I find all of them without omitting something?

Comment: I gave you an answer, please look below.

Comment: Both your examples of ABCDEF mapping are increasing, but that's not required. Another combination could be 825094 or 987610.

Comment: @Νεφέλη Κάσα Please see if my edit to your question is correct and rollback if it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035007/find-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-digits#comment118494527_67035007) I understand you're not interested now in the input data analysis, i.e. recognizing how many different letters (independent variables) there are in the problem, nor representing their positions in the equation you solve, or a method for testing whether some assignment of one-digit numbers to those variables satisfies the equation.

You just look for a way to find all possible assignments of one-digit numbers to those variables.

So, having a number of digits allowed `n=10` and a number of distinct letters used (variables in the solution) `k` you need to find

1. all C(n,k) combinations of digits to be assigned, and
2. for each combination, all its k! permutations, that is distinct orderings in assignment to letters/variables.

Possibly the most efficient methods of finding those combinations and permutations are recursive. However, that would make you to call next phase deep at the bottom of recursion, and the code would be hard to understand. So I'd prefer a less efficient but far more legible iterative approach.

Let's declare an array of values to be assigned to variables. We do not know in advance, how many variables will be needed, but certainly it's not more than 10 (because the problem defines a constraint that each variable (letter) is assigned a distinct number, and there are at most 10 distinct digits to assign). So:

```
int values[10];
```

Now, let's create the first combination. It will consist of first possible `k` digits, that is `0` through `k-1`:

```
void FirstCombination(int values[], int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        values[i] = i;
}
```

We will have to create a new combination from the current one. Usually this can be done by simply incrementing the last number. It will modify a chosen sequence for example like this:

```
    2, 3, 7  →  2, 3, 8
```

But what happens, if the last value is `9` already?

```
    2, 3, 9  →  2, 3, ???
```

Well, we can check if the one-but-last value can be incremented (which means it's less than `8`), and increment that if so, then set the last value greater by one from that:

```
    2, 3, 9  →  2, 3  →  2, 4  →  2, 4, 5
```

That obviously goes down to the first element:

```
    2,7,8,9  →  2  →  3  →  3,4,5,6
```

If that succeeds we `return` a 'true' value (`1`) to indicate we found a new valid combination, otherwise (none value can be incremented) we return 'false' (`0`):

```
int NextCombination(int values[], int n, int k)
{
    for (int i = k-1; i >= 0; i--)   // from the last number backwards
    {
        if (values[i] < n + i - k)   // can this be incremented?
        {
            values[i] ++;            // increment
            while (++i < k)          // reset following values
                values[i] = values[i - 1] + 1;

            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then we can iterate over all combinations with a simple loop:

```
int n = 10;
int values[10];

FirstCombination(values, k);
do {
    //
    // ... process the combination here ...
    //
} while (NextCombination(values, n, k));
```

A convenient feature of these two functions is that each combination delivered is given in an ascending order.

Let's see now how we can build all the permutations of the given array. Having the combination in an ascending order gives us a nice start for generating them in the lexicographic ('alphabetic') order, which can be understood the 'numbers' generated by resulting sequences of digits make an ascending order themselves. For example,

```
    2, 4, 5
    2, 5, 4
    4, 2, 5
    4, 5, 2
    5, 2, 4
    5, 4, 2
```

To achieve this let's find a decreasing tail of the sequence. If it is the whole sequence, we have the last permutation (in the lexicographic order) so we're done. Otherwise we take the number preceding the tail and exchange it with the next greater item from the tail. Then we reverse the tail. Here are some examples:

```
sequence    tail        next grtr   exchange    reverse     result
1 3 5 6 7   1 3 5 6[7]  1 3 5 6<7>  1 3 5 7[6]  1 3 5 7[6]  1 3 5 7 6
1 5 7 6 3   1 5[7 6 3]  1 5 7<6>3   1 6[7 5 3]  1 6[3 5 7]  1 6 3 5 7
7 6 5 3 1  [7 6 5 3 1]    none        none     [1 3 5 6 7]  1 3 5 6 7  DONE
```

This way we end up with the first permutation restored, which is a convenient point to continue searching for a next combination.

```
int NextPermutation(int values[], int k)
{
    // find the tail beginning
    int tail = k-1;
    while (tail > 0 && values[tail-1] > values[tail])
        tail --;

    // not the last permutation?
    if (tail > 0)
    {
        int nextGreater = k - 1;
        while (values[nextGreater] < values[tail - 1])
            nextGreater --;

        // found; now swap
        int tmp = values[tail - 1];
        values[tail - 1] = values[nextGreater];
        values[nextGreater] = tmp;
    }

    // reverse the tail
    int left = tail, right = k - 1;
    while (left < right)
    {
        int tmp = values[left];
        values[left] = values[right];
        values[right] = tmp;
        left ++; right --;
    }

    return tail > 0;  // return 'true' if it wasn't the last permutation
}
```

Now we can iterate through all combinations and their permutations with two nested loops:

```
int n = 10;
int values[10];

FirstCombination(values, k);
do {
    do {
        //
        // ... process the permutation here ...
        //
    } while (NextPermutation(values, k));
} while (NextCombination(values, n, k));
```

Or, thanks to the short-circuit method of boolean operators evaluation, with a single loop with a compound condition:

```
int n = 10;
int values[10];

FirstCombination(values, k);
do {
    //
    // ... process the permutation here ...
    //
} while (NextPermutation(values, k) || NextCombination(values, n, k));
```

See it working at godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/YKe8s69qT

Inside the loop you need to evaluate the three input expressions by applying `values` to corresponding letters, then verify the equality holds. When evaluating the input ciphers be aware the same value can be applied several times, like two `B`, two `A` and two `L` in `BASEBALL`.

There is one additional difficulty which you did not mention: cryptarithmetic puzzles usually assume zero can not be assigned as a leading digit. For example, `15+8=23` is a valid solution for `AB+C=DE`, but `07+5=12` is not. So you should be aware which letters are used as initials in the three words and not process permutations that assign zero to any of them.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so so much for putting the effort!

Answer (score 0):

What you asking for is more a mathematical problem than a programmer problem.

This is probably the formula you are searching for.

```
  (N_a*10^n + ... + B_a*10^1 + A_a*10^0)
+ (N_b*10^n + ... + B_b*10^1 + A_b*10^0)
----------------------------------------
= (N_c*10^n + ... + B_c*10^1 + A_c*10^0)
```

So in your example for "BASE + BALL = GAMES", the formula would be like:

```
           (B*10^3 + A*10^2 + S*10^1 + E*10^0)
+          (B*10^3 + A*10^2 + L*10^1 + L*10^0)
----------------------------------------------
= (G*10^4 + A*10^3 + M*10^2 + E*10^1 + S*10^0)
```

This is an linear equation with 7 unknowns.

The following term may also be written as:

```
              (B*10^3 + A*10^2 + S*10^1 + E*10^0)
+             (B*10^3 + A*10^2 + L*10^1 + L*10^0)
-------------------------------------------------
= (2*B*10^3 + 2*A*10^2 + (S+L)*10^1 + (E+L)*10^0)
```

Resulting in:

```
2*B*10^3 + 2*A*10^2 + (S+L)*10^1 + (E+L)*10^0 = G*10^4 + A*10^3 + M*10^2 + E*10^1 + S*10^0
```

The easiest solution for all possible terms would be:

```
A=0, B=0, E=0, G=0, L=0, S=0, M=0
```

But I guess, that's not what you are looking for.

One other very important fact is, that all unknowns must be a natural number from inclusive 0 to inclusive 9, [0, 9]. But like I've shown, you need to look carefully when using 0, because that could create unwanted results.

So maybe just look for all natural numbers from inclusive 1 to inclusive 9, [1, 9].

**PS read about number crunching algorithms**

**PPS a very stupid algorithm would be:**

```
int number_crunching = 1;
int A = B = E = G = L = S = M = 1;
while(number_crunching == 1){
    if(B*2000 + A*200 + (S+L)*10 + E + L == G*10000 + A*1000 + M*100 + E*10 + S)
    {
        number_crunching = 0; //found a solution
        break;
    }
    if(++A == 10){
        A = 1;
        if(++B == 10){
            B = 1;
            if(++E == 10){
                E = 1;
                if(++G == 10){
                    G = 1;
                    if(++L == 10){
                        L = 1;
                        if(++S == 10){
                            S = 1;
                            if(++M == 10){
                                number_crunching = -1; //found no solution
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

PPPS I've not tested the loop, but you should know now how to try to solve your problem

Comment: PS I oversaw that the to be searched digits must be unique, so my example program is not completly right, but I guess you know how to change it in the way you need it; this also removes the problem of the 0

Comment: As far as I can tell on the first glimpse, your algorithm will test _many_ combinations of equal values, for example `A, B, C` all equal `3`, some of which may give a solution correct (satisfying the given equation) but invalid (values assigned to letter must be unique).

Comment: Whoops, overlooked your comment. :)