# Is it possible to change this recursion to a iteration without stack?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, iteration, permutation

The following code uses depth-first search algorithm to generate permutations recursively, I want to know how to change to iteration equivalent without a stack(Pointers can be used). Note that this is very similar to traversing a tree, I try to use the method mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988138/2431184), but it is always unsuccessful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3
int A[N];

void dfs(int n, int mask) {
    if (n == N) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", A[j]);
        }
        puts("");
    } else
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if ((mask & (1 << i)) == 0) {
                A[n] = i + 1;
                dfs(n + 1, mask | (1 << i));
            }
}

int main() {
    dfs(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: the q&a you link already states that this is possible (assuming it is equivalent to traversing a tree). "is it possible?" questions are not so good, because the answer is either just a "yes" or "no". Interpreting it as "please gimme the codez?!" also doesnt make it a good question. When you have issues with code better show that code, no matter how broken. Currently it is unclear why you were not sucessful by applying that answer.

Comment: You may want to see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67038660/733637) to the _[Find all possible combinations of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035007/find-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers)_ question. It's not the same algorithm as yours, and it's in C, not C++, but I hope it may be helpful.

Comment: "Can I rewrite this stack-based algorithm without a stack?... but I want it to be exactly the same algorithm" is a very annoying question.  The Pandita algorithm is similar, but it uses the sequence itself as the stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752319/algorithm-to-list-unique-permutations-of-string-with-duplicate-letters/40756214#40756214

Comment: Changing a question to make existing, correct answers wrong is generally viewed as [_bad behavior_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much).

Comment: @DrewDormann I am with you, but also consider that already the original question stated " I want to know how to change to iteration equivalent without a stack(Pointers can be used)"

Comment: @DrewDormann and now that I think about it the answer does answer that ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number then I'm with you.

Comment: please don't tag C and C++ unless the question is about interoperation between the two (different) languages. And when you realize that the question was not exactly asking what you wanted to ask for it is better to open a new question rather than to invalidate existing answers

Comment: @expression given your rejection of an answer that uses `<algorithm>`, is this possibly a homework assignment?  The answer that's here now both _"use[s] iteration"_ and _"rewrite[s] the original algorithm"_

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t think about it clearly at the beginning. I should add another question, but someone has already answered it. Now I can’t delete the question.

Comment: @expression I have rolled back this question to what it was when an answer was given.  You are very welcome to ask a new question.  Do be careful when choosing between [c] and [c++] tags.  They are not the same.

Comment: Usually DFS requires a stack-like structure. You could use `std::stack` for that, but that's not much different from recursion. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-depth-first-traversal/) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to generate permutations.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define N 3
int A[N];

void perm() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = i + 1;
    }
    do {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", A[j]);
        }
        puts("");
    } while (std::next_permutation(A, A + N));
}

int main() {
    perm();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I know this way. What I want to know is how to use iteration to rewrite the original algorithm.

Comment: `#define N 3` is ugly and should be replaced by `const` or `constexpr`. There is [guideline for that](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-macros2).

Comment: @expression the link has a [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation#Possible_implementation)